# iPhone Keyboard hiding a UITextView when it comes in?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I am working on an iPhone Application and am attempting to get a Landscape View for a simple, editable UITextView working.

Both interface layouts are specified in NIB files, and I have succeeded in loading them and migrating data when the devices rotates.

However, the UITextView in the Landscape version "runs away" from the iPhone Keyboard, making it impossible to see what you're editing. I have no idea why it is doing this--can anybody help?

Thanks in Advance!

VIDEO OF PROBLEM: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWBKBA_KjQ

Comment: Perhaps instead of a video, you might post some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No way to know what you are doing without some code, but you should try something like this:

```
- (void) animateTextField: (UITextView*) textView up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Call this from where you think appropiate (UIKeyboardWillShowNotigication, for instance) and well, it will animate your view in order to show the textview.

Comment: Can you post an example where to call it from?